# Index out of bound while reading a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a tab separated file that I am trying to parse and for that I am doing this :

header of my file :

```
chrom   coord   ref_base    var_base    A   C   G   T
17  26695663    G   A   1   0   1934    0
17  26695664    T   A   1   0   1   1935
```

my code is :

```
counts = pd.read_csv(args.counts_file, sep='\t')
toto = counts[(counts['chrom'].astype(str) == "17") & (counts['coord'].astype(str) == "26695663")]
print toto["G"].values[0]
```

this function returns the number wanted which is 1934

Now when I try to create a function that takes arguments the dataframe read from the file, I wrote this function

```
def get_foreground_counts(chrom, coord, counts, ref_base, var_base):

     foreground_counts = counts[(counts['chrom'] == chrom) & (counts['coord'] == coord)]

     foreground_ref_counts = foreground_counts[ref_base].values[0]

     foreground_var_counts = foreground_counts[var_base].values[0]

     return foreground_ref_counts, foreground_var_counts
```

I got this error that I am trying to figure out but still cant see why

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 203, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "test.py", line 71, in main
    foreground_ref_counts, foreground_var_counts = get_foreground_counts(chrom, coord, counts, ref_base, var_base)
  File "test.py", line 137, in get_foreground_counts
    foreground_ref_counts = foreground_counts[ref_base].values[0]
IndexError: index out of bounds
```

Any idea why ?

Thanks

*UPDATE*

- When I try to print foreground_counts[ref_base].values I get this `[]`
- What I am passing to the function is chrom (string), coord(string), counts(panda dataframe), ref_base (string), var_base(string) )

Comment: What do you get from printing `foreground_counts[ref_base].values` before the error occurs?

Comment: What are you passing the function? ...it's out of bounds as it's empty.

Comment: Christian and Andy I updated the question answering your questions

Comment: Can you please edit this into a reproducible example?  Show what specific values you are passing to the function, based on what's provided it seems like either your `chrome` or `chord` don't exist in the DataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function, your filter does return zero rows, that's why you get the error. It seems you forgot the `.astype(str)` in your function's first line.

You could either cast the column type before calling the function or modify that line. The former would be a better approach if you really need to use a string type, otherwise why don't you use integer values for the comparison?.

Comment: Thank you @Rho, yes that was it, comparing using int solved my issue indeed, thanks a lot